# how to display image from a directory?

Tags: grails

as i know, we always diplay a image from `assets/image` folder 
for example like this..

```
<asset:image src='settings.png' style="height: 20px" alt="logout"/>
```

but how if my images's file are located in root directory? 
like

`/home/file/images.png -->my image's file
/root/tomcat8/webapp/alkd.war`

`home` and `root` folder are in the same level

i am using grails 3.1.1

i am trying to display more than 10 images

i tried to add some code to `applicaiton.yml` like this..

http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/#configuration-2

but i get this error on startup..

```
`ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [assets/perpage/memberCreate-5e70ab1b20bb09d756c62afce8cb0d65.js] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:64) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at asset.pipeline.AssetPipelineBootStrap$_closure1$_closure2.doCall(AssetPipelineBootStrap.groovy:23) ~[asset-pipeline-3.0.15.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2015) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2068) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$164.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at asset.pipeline.AssetPipelineBootStrap$_closure1.doCall(AssetPipelineBootStrap.groovy:19) ~[asset-pipeline-3.0.15.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1084) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by getting Tomcat root and append directory/file names e.g.

```
def baseDir = System.getProperty( 'catalina.base' )
def imagesDir = "${baseDir}\webapps\myapp\images"
```

Comment: hmm..i dont get it.

Comment: i use this code in `controller`? 
if in folder `assets`, we can access it with `abc.com/assets/34724927384.jpg`
but how about your answers? am i possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to [official docs](https://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html):

> Serving Assets from External Storage Directory
>
> Asset Pipeline can be configured to copy your assets files out to an external storage path. This can be useful for setting up your web server (e.g. nginx) to directly serve your static assets. To do so, simply define a config variable in your Config.groovy environment block.
>
> ```
> environments {
>     production {
>         grails.assets.storagePath = "/full/path/to/storage"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> It is also possible to configure a custom CDN asset URL for serving these assets:
>
> ```
> environments {
>         production {
>             grails.assets.url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/asset-pipe/assets/"
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: with this solution, when i restart my app, the storage will be clean up or not?

Comment: hi.. i tried to create like this...http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/#configuration-2
check my update questio